# FileWriter - Write to .txt within project but outside current directory

Tags: java

So I am generating data and appending it to a text file.

Instead of using `FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("addressList.txt");` I need the file path to be in another package where I have created the addressList.txt file. It says System cannot find path error.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Eclipse?

Comment: And in your other package, are you setting your filename in a String? Make it public, I guess...

Comment: Eclipse. The file is created in another package, but I am writing to that file from another package.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to write to a file that's in your project. Use an external directory for storing mutable data, the project is for code, config and other read-only content. (By read-only I mean read-only from the program's point of view.)

Comment: Create and write a small test file. It should go to the base of your Eclipse project, and you can see it by pressing F5 (Refresh) on your project. Then use \\.. to go up the directory hierarchy and //resource to go down the directory hierarchy to the resource folder.  You can also right-click on the folders, bring up Properties, and see where the file system thinks the file is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

depending on how you are running this the path may be readable but not be writable.  Resources in JAR files are generally static and should be treated as readonly.

If you are trying to create a list of per user settings (addresses stored in a list) you should consider using the System objects getenv(string) method to locate the users temporary storage and copy the default file there.  After copying the default file you will be free to update the file exactly as normal.

Reference:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv(java.lang.String)

Comment: +1, even if in your specific deployment resources on the classpath aren't read-only, you should always treat them as such.